# vue 3, Firebase, Pinia and reactivity

Tags: firebase, vue.js, pinia

I'm using Pinia in combination with Firebase for user management.
This is the user store I've defined:

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';
import { ref } from 'vue';
import { useFirebase } from '../composables/useFirebase';
import { 
   createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
   signInWithEmailAndPassword,
   signOut } from 'firebase/auth';

export const useUserStore = defineStore('user', () => {
   const { auth } = useFirebase();
   const user = ref(null);
   const error = ref(null);


  async function createUser(email, password) {
    createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
      .then((userCredential) => {
         user.value = userCredential.user;
         error.value = '';

    })
      .catch((err) => {
        error.value = err.message;
      });
  };

  function loginUser(email, password) {
    signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
      .then((userCredential) => {
         user.value = userCredential.user;
         error.value = null;
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        error.value = err.message;
      });
  }

  function logoutUser() {
    signOut(auth).then(() => console.log('User logged out'))
      .catch((err) => {
        error.value = err.message;
      })
  }

  return { 
    createUser,
    loginUser,
    logoutUser,
    user,
    error,
  }
});
```

Ant the view where I'd like to register a new user:

```
    <template>
    <div>
        <h1 class="mx-auto text-center font-bold texy-gray-600 text-4xl">Register new user</h1>
        <UserForm actionType="Register" @userCreds="registerUser"/>
        {{ userEmail }} - {{ userPassword }}
        <p v-if="error">{{ error }}</p>
    </div>
   </template>

  <script setup>

  import { ref } from 'vue';
  import { useUserStore } from '../stores/user';
  import UserForm from '../components/forms/UserForm.vue';

  const userEmail = ref(null);
  const userPassword = ref(null);

  const { createUser, error } = useUserStore();

  const registerUser = async (userCreds) => {
    userEmail.value = userCreds.email.value;
    userPassword.value = userCreds.password.value;

    await createUser(userEmail.value, userPassword.value);
    if(error.value) { 
        console.log(error.value);
    }
  };
```

User registration with Firebase works so far. However, when there is an error (e.g., a user with that email exists already), I'd expect that in the view because of

```
const { createUser, error } = useUserStore();
```

error will be a ref (as is was defined in the store) and error.value will contain the error message.

But actually it does not work.

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null
> (reading 'value')
> at registerUser (RegisterView.vue:26:14)

Furthermore, vscode complains when I hover over error.value here:

```
const registerUser = async (userCreds) => {
userEmail.value = userCreds.email.value;
userPassword.value = userCreds.password.value;

await createUser(userEmail.value, userPassword.value);
if(error.value) { 
    console.log(error.value);
}
```

};

> Property 'value' may not exist on type string.

What is the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

The [Pinia documentation](https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/) describes the issue:

> Note that store is an object wrapped with reactive, meaning there is no need to write .value after getters but, like props in setup, we cannot destructure it. In order to extract properties from the store while keeping its reactivity, you need to use storeToRefs(). It will create refs for every reactive property.

Using storeToRefs like in this example works:

```
<script setup>
import { storeToRefs } from 'pinia'

const store = useCounterStore()
// `name` and `doubleCount` are reactive refs
// This will also extract refs for properties added by plugins
// but skip any action or non reactive (non ref/reactive) property
const { name, doubleCount } = storeToRefs(store)
// the increment action can just be destructured
const { increment } = store
</script>
```